# Bounds on a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I am currently in the middle of a proof where it would be nice to have some estimates on the size of a quadratic form. In particular, I am looking at
$$x^TAx$$
where $A$ is "small" (in the analyst's sense of small). So far I have done the obvious thing:
$$|x^TAx| = |x \cdot Ax| \leq ||x||\cdot||Ax|| \leq ||x|| \cdot ||A|| \cdot ||x|| = ||A||\cdot||x||^2.$$
This is a bit of an open ended question, but what else can I do? What information about $A$ (or $x$?) did I lose when I estimated?

Comment: Please be a little clearer about what your question is exactly.

Comment: I am looking for any types of bounds on quadratic forms.

Answer (score 5):

If $A$ is symmetric, you have not lost anything, since for such a matrix the operator norm is equal to $\sup\{|x^TAx| : \|x\|=1\}$, which is also the largest absolute value of an eigenvalue.

For general $A$, you can gain something by writing it as 
$$A = \frac12(A+A^T)+\frac12(A-A^T)$$
where the second term does not contribute to $x^TAx$. Hence 
$$|x^TAx| \le \frac12\|A+A^T\|\ \|x\|^2$$

Comment: Is this the best bound we can obtain?

Comment: @user369210 For general $x$, yes. Equality is obtained if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A+A^\top$ with the maximal eigenvalue (in magnitude).

Answer (score 2):

You could have also further put a bound on $\lVert x\rVert ^2$ assuming the norm is an l2 norm:
$$ \lVert x\rVert_2 \le \sqrt n*\lVert x\rVert_\infty   $$

$n$ being the size of the vector $x$. Depending on what sort of data one might have available with them regarding $x$ and $A$, other bounds could also be derived.

The following sources might be helpful:

- https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/matrixnorm.pdf
- [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis515/cis515-11-sl4.pdf](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis515/cis515-11-sl4.pdf)